# Plot line with labels

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot

Having a plot with several traces. I want to plot one trace with labels.

```
plot "-" ls 3 notitle ,\
     "-" ls 4 title "Trace 1", \
     "-"  ls 5 title "Trace 2" ,\
     "-" with points ls 6 notitle
P1 1.5 17.962924780409974
P2 1.7 16.87322975464215
P3 1.9 15.960477502420257
P4 2.1 15.181442305531792
P5 2.3000000000000003 14.506370414707312
P6 2.5000000000000004 13.914021704740868
P7 2.7000000000000006 13.38877362790406
P8 2.900000000000001 12.918844829323474
P9 3.100000000000001 12.495160353435423
P10 3.300000000000001 12.110601416389963
e
...
```

How can I plot the first traces so that `labels` with `P0` to `P10` appear next to that point?

Answer (score 4):

In general it is easier, when your data is stored in a file. So to keep things short I assume here that the data is read from "Datafile.dat"

You can plot a label instead of a point at the given position if you use the option "with labels" for your plot.

```
plot "Datafile.txt" using 2:3:1 with labels
```

The first two arguments of "using" specify the (x,y) position, while the 3rd one tells where the label is.

Now this will display only the points but not the labels. So we can just add another which displays the points only and also add an offset to the labels (0.05) so the labels dont overlap with the points:

```
plot "Datafile.txt" using ($2+0.05):($3+0.05):1 with labels, "" using 2:3
```

Now if you want to provide different options (ls, title etc.) for each trace, you can apply the "every" option to select a particular line (trace). for example "every ::1::1 " will plot only the 2nd trace (first line is "0" ).

Alltogether, you should be fine with this solution:

```
plot "Datafile.txt" u ($2+0.05):($3+0.05):1 with labels notitle,\
     "" u 2:3 ev ::0::0 ls 3 "Trace 1",\
     "" u 2:3 ev ::1::1 ls 4 "Trace 2",\
     "" u 2:3 ev ::2 ls 6 notitle
```